# Order the contents of lists of lists by their ID

Tags: python

Imagine I have a random number of lists of lists, such that every list has the following format: `[[%f, %s], [%f, %s], ...]`. So each list has a random number of pairs of a float and a string.

I want to compare all elements of all lists, and write them in another separate list in order of their float value.

Example:
If my input lists are

```
a = [[4.0, "hello"], [3.5, "world"]]
b = [[1.1, "stack"], [2.1, "overflow"], [10.0, "love"], [0.5, "python"]]
c = [[5.6, "programming"]]
```

I want the output list to be

```
final = [[0.5, "python"], [1.1, "stack"], [2.1, "overflow"], [3.5, "world"], [4.0, "hello"], [5.6, "programming"], [10.0, "love"]]
```

Keep in mind that I don't know how many lists I'll have as an input, nor do I know how many elements does each list have.
The only solutions I could come up with can't account for those two things, and I'm all out of ideas on how to proceed.

As a last note: this is my first question here, so if I've done something wrong, please let me know so I can fix that and have a proper answer! Thank you.

Comment: While your question is very well written, the reason you're being downvoted is because you've not showed any attempt at solving the answer yourself.

Comment: Perhaps, @Peter but I think it may have more to do with "does not show research effort" as this question is very searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a `key` function which provides the parameters to sort by - in this case, sort by the first element in each sub-list - i.e. the float value.

```py
a = [[4.0, "hello"], [3.5, "world"]]
b = [[1.1, "stack"], [2.1, "overflow"], [10.0, "love"], [0.5, "python"]]
c = [[5.6, "programming"]]

print(sorted(a + b + c, key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

I would also suggest using `itemgetter`, which might appear a bit more Pythonic:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

print(sorted(a + b + c, key=itemgetter(0)))
```

Result:

```
[[0.5, 'python'], [1.1, 'stack'], [2.1, 'overflow'], [3.5, 'world'], [4.0, 'hello'], [5.6, 'programming'], [10.0, 'love']]
```

---

Some quick benchmarks show that `operator.itemgetter` might be a little faster:

```py
from timeit import timeit
print(f"Sorted -> lambda:      {timeit('sorted(a + b + c, key=lambda x: x[0])', globals=globals()):.3f}")
print(f"Sorted -> itemgetter:  {timeit('sorted(a + b + c, key=itemgetter(0))', globals=globals()):.3f}")
```

Benchmark results:

```
Sorted -> lambda:      0.943
Sorted -> itemgetter:  0.725
```